# Rails AJAX form not re-populating fields after validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a Rails 5.2.0 app with `simple_form` gem. In the setup below I am creating a new `Note` with an AJAX form. I can create a new record just fine.

However, when the validation on the form fails (title and body attributes), it is re-rendering the `_new.html.erb` partial but without filling the form fields with the data that was present before the user submitted the form.

How do I keep the data after the validation fails?

`book.rb`

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notes
end
```

`note.rb`

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book

  validates :title, :body, presence: true
end
```

`notes_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @note = Note.new

  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js {}
  end
end

def create 
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @note = @book.notes.create(note_params)

  if @note.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_book_path(id: @book.id, user_id: current_user.slug) }
      format.js { redirect_to user_book_path(id: @book.id, user_id: current_user.slug) }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :new }
      format.js {render :new}
    end
  end
end
```

`_new.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for [book, Note.new], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "title", label: false, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :body, placeholder: "title", label: false, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Create note" %>
<% end %>
```

`new.js.erb`

```
$("#show-edit-note").html("<%= j render partial: 'notes/new', locals: { book: @book, note: @note } %>");
```

Comment: Add required to your form attributes, to validate presence on client side!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that you use `Note.new` here:

```
<%= simple_form_for [book, Note.new], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "title", label: false, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :body, placeholder: "title", label: false, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Create note" %>
<% end %>
```

So, you'll never have any values in the form because the form is always based on a new `Note` object.

Since you're instantiating `@note` in both your `new` and `create` actions, I believe you should be doing:

```
<%= simple_form_for [book, @note], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "title", label: false, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :body, placeholder: "title", label: false, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Create note" %>
<% end %>
```

I don't use `simple_form`, so it's a shot in the dark.

Also, as John Gallagher states in the comments, this:

```
@note = @book.notes.create(note_params)
```

Should really be this:

```
@note = @book.notes.build(note_params)
```

When instantiating something like `@note`, it's typical to use `.build` instead of `.create` because `.build` doesn't save `@note` which makes the `if @note.save` conditional a little more sensible.